# Dart doesn't catch Platform Exceptions in try/catch

Tags: dart, exception

I have the following code, which performs authentication in my app:

```
Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User user = userCredential.user;
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error).toString();
      return null;
    }
  }
```

If I enter wrong email and password I would get multiple `Exceptions`, including `FirebaseAuthException` and `PlatformException`. The code handles the `FirebaseAuthException` fine, but when it comes to `PlatformException`, the code just crashes. I have tried changing the code `try/catch` statement to `on PlatformException catch {...}` but nothing works.

Comment: Most likely the `PlatformException` is coming from somewhere else. A single function call *cannot* throw multiple exceptions. If you get multiple exceptions, then some of them are most likely uncaught asynchronous exceptions, and they never reach your code where your `catch` can handle them.

Comment: I tried debugging it, but with no success. The debugger line is in the `try/catch` statement when the exception is thrown. Any reason why the debugger wouldn't work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You misplaces your `toString`.

`print` returns a void, so that's why it throws an exception inside your `catch` clause.

Do `print(error);` instead of `print(error).toString();`

Comment: Completely true, but that error should not throw any `PlatformException`s. If `print(...).toString();` is allowed at all, it will do nothing. The `print` function returns `null` at type `void`, and calling `toString()` on `null` is safe. It should be a *compile-time* error to call anything on a `void`-typed expression, though.

Comment: The code never makes it to the `catch` part, so the print statements don't have any effect on it.